# EF 4.1 - Add items to collection property that is virtual

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF 4.1 code first. Given the following class snippet:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public virtual ICollection<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I have this in the database context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

I wanted to make sure that lazy loading is not involved here.

The issue I have is that, without the `virtual` keyword on the Hospitals property, when I retrieve a doctor that does have a hospital associated with him, the collection is empty.
By including the `virtual` keyword, the hospitals collection does contain 1 item, which is what I expect.

The problem is that, when I want to create a brand new doctor and associate him with a hospital immediately, I get a `Null reference` exception, since the Hospitals property has not been initialised yet.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? How can I add items to the Hospitals upon creating a new doctor.

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your code is something what you usually see in all examples but to make this work this one is much better:

```
public class Doctor
{
    private ICollection<Hospital> _hospitals;
    public virtual ICollection<Hospital> Hospitals 
    { 
        get { return _hospitals ?? (_hospitals = new HashSet<Hospital>()); }
        set { _hospitals = value } 
    }
}
```

If you don't use `virtual` keyword EF will not initialize collection for you. In the same time if you create brand new `Doctor` via its constructor you must handle initialization yourselves.

Comment: Every time I see one of your posts it solves my issues. If you had a book on EF I would buy it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you.

```
public class Doctor
{
    public Doctor()
    {
       Hospitals = new ICollection<Hospital>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Hospital> Hospitals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah in the end, that's what I did - creating new instance in the ctor.